# Search for data in Excel 2010 that can be anywhere in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to search for data anywhere in a column.  I have the following formula but I think I need a wild card.  My data may be in cell `J2012` instead of `J2`. Suggestions?

```
=IF( COUNTIF($A:$A,$J2)<>0, "-", "Not in J")
```

Comment: are you trying to see if anything in column A matches anything in column J, or are you trying to look for a specific value? also, do you just want to know if it exists, or do you want to know where your data is?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula appears functional to me, but I wonder if you have it backwards of how you want it to work.  Right now, it is searching the whole of column A for the contents of cell J2.  Because you have `Countif() <> 0` it will return "Not in J" if the contents of J2 are found anywhere in column A.  If you want it to return "Not in J" if it **isn't** found in the column, I suggest you change the `<>` to an `=` to achieve this.  If I've misunderstood your objective, perhaps you can provide some more details of how your data is set up and what you are trying to check.

---

**EDIT:**

If what you're trying to accomplish is this:

[image]

Then you should use the formula `=IF(COUNTIF($J:$J,"*"&A1&"*"), "-", "Not in J")` like this:

[image]